# Check Timestamp Then Redis Publish An Event?

Tags: php, laravel, events, redis, socket.io

This isnt so much an issue more of a noobie question as I am not a redis god (my beard isnt that long yet). My app is a  realtime roulette game where a game is auto created by laravel and has a set end timestamp (60 seconds from creation). I have no clue how to check to see when the time ends to send out an event. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your initial timestamp is store in redis then what you can do is

fetch that time then get the current timestamp and compare it something like this

```
$time = //time from your redis

if((time() - $time) > 60){
    echo 'past 1 minute';
}
```